# How to have smooth scroll when navigation link is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, modal-dialog

I have 3 links in my navigation bar and whenever they are pressed I would like a smooth scroll to their area on the page. I have the anchors set up, but I do not have any scripting experience so I would need help with the actual smooth scroll. Can any of you tell me what I would need to do? I have also created a JSFIDDLE here: https://jsfiddle.net/d9oxdxbo/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="test_webpage.html#about">ABOUT
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="test_webpage.html#coupons">COUPONS
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="test_webpage.html#feedback">FEEDBACK
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/dr3y7v/vintage.png" height="660px" width="100%">
    <h2>
      <span style="background-color: rgba(26, 102, 255, 0.75)">BRINGING YOU CONVENIENCE
      </span>
    </h2>
    <h3>
      <span style="background-color: rgba(26, 102, 255, 0.75)">SINCE THE 2000's
      </span>
    </h3>
    <div id='about'>
      <a id="about" name='about'>
        <div id='opaque'>
          <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/bS5nja/gas_station_hero_image.jpg" height="680px" width="100%">
        </div>
        <h4>WHO WE ARE
        </h4>
        <div id='divp2'> 
          <p>WE ARE A SMALL CONVENIENCE STORE LOCATED IN THE HEART OF CARY, NORTH CAROLINA. WE SPECIALIZE IN CRAFT BEER AND EXQUISITE WINE. WE HAVE ALL YOUR QUICK GROCERY NEEDS. WE HAVE THE BEST PRICES IN OUR AREA GUARANTEED! COME VISIT US FOR A TRULY ENLIGHTENING EXPERIENCE! WE ARE ON GOOGLE SO IF YOU WANT TO SEE OUR REVIEWS OR GIVE US ONE, YOU CAN!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id='divp'>
          <p>YOU MIGHT BE WONDERING, WHY SHOULD I COME HERE? WHAT MAKES THIS GAS STATION DIFFERENT FROM OTHER GAS STATIONS? WELL, WITH EXCELLENT STAFF, LOW PRICES, AND CLEAN FLOORS, THE BETTER QUESTION SHOULD BE, WHY SHOULDN'T I COME HERE! WE HOPE YOU COME TO OUR STORE AND HAVE A FABULOUS EXPERIENCE. IF YOU DO EXPERIENCE ANY DIFFICULTIES DURING YOUR TIME HERE, PLEASE FEEL FREE TO CONTACT THE MANAGER. HE WILL RESOLVE YOUR COMPLAINTS IN NO TIME!
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id='coupons'>
      <a id="coupons" name='coupons'>
        <div style="float:left">  
          <img id='myImg' src="https://preview.ibb.co/jBYUxv/coupon1.png" id="i1" height="300px" width="600px">
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">×
            </span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div id='pformat'>
          <p>COUPONS FOR YOU!
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id='feedback'>
      <a id="feedback" name='feedback'>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: mediumblue;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 75px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: darkblue;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 265px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  h4 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 60px;
    top: 700px;
    color: #1A66FF;
  }
  #divp2{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'hind';
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    top: 900px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    font-weight: 0;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'hind';
    src: url('C:/Users/lakes/Desktop/hind2.ttf')
  }
  #pformat{
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-left: 620px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1450px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #1A66FF;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #opaque {
    opacity: .2;
  }
  #divp {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'hind';
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1075px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
  }
  #myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  #myImg:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  /* The Modal (background) */
  .modal {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px;
    /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  /* Modal Content (image) */
  .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  /* Caption of Modal Image */
  #caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
  }
  /* Add Animation */
  .modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0)}
    to {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1)}
  }
  @keyframes zoom {
    from {
      transform: scale(0.1)}
    to {
      transform: scale(1)}
  }
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

JS

```
  // Get the modal
          var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
          // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
          var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
          var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
          img.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
          }
          // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
          var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
          // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
          span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your anchor tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a'). Click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('the link div').offset().top}, 'slow'); 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Was I just supposed to add this within the script tag? I did that but nothing changed.

Comment: Did this work for you? Because I tried it and nothing happened.

Comment: Thats what i usually use for a smooth scroll. Let me see what your are trying.